# How do you solve a linear equation of matrices?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

The function Solve works fine for scalars:

```
In[]:= Solve[A x - x B + C == 0, x]
Out[]= {{x -> -(C/(A - B))}}
```

When using matrices however,

```
mA = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
mB = {{2, 0}, {0, 2}};
mC = {{3, 1}, {0, 3}};

Solve[mA.x - x.mB + mC == 0, x]

Out[]= {}
```

There is no output, though there should be (x={{3,1},{0,3}}, I guess). The same happens when the matrix multiplication operator "." is replaced with a white space.

How can linear matrix equations like these be solved?

Comment: @Artes I'm sorry, I don't see how the answer to the linked question could solve a linear system like this (note also that `x` is multiplied from the **left** with `mA` and from the **right** with `mB`).

Comment: You should note that this is a so-called Lyapunov equation and Mathematica has a dedicated function for solving it! (At least for the cases where C is positive definite)

Comment: @sebhofer That's pretty sweet, it's a pity then that this is just a trial equation for something bigger.

Comment: Oh, also note that I haven't realized your equation has two distinct matrices A and B so its not a Lyapunov equation. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
With[{x = Array[x, Dimensions[mA]]}, Solve[mA .x - x. mB + mC == 0, Flatten@x]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
With[{x = Array[x, Dimensions[mA]]},  x /. Solve[mA .x - x. mB + mC == 0, Flatten@x]]
```

> {{{3, 1}, {0, 3}}}